# How to generate an impulse response in practical way

Tags: waveform

The impulse response is the derivative of the step response. But if I simply use differentiator, the signal seems to be unstable.

Can I generate an impulse response using waves in normal waveform generator?

Comment: What signal? Where do you use it? What for? What waves in what generator? Simulation or practice?

Comment: generate an impulse and measure the response.

Comment: `Can I generate an impulse response using waves in normal waveform generator?` I think you want to generate an impulse (i.e. Dirac-Delta). Because impulse "response" is what you get from the system when the input is a Dirac-Delta impulse.

Answer (score 3):

An impulse is an ideal waveform (zero width) that cannot be generated with real equipment. However it can be approximated with a narrow pulse. The accuracy of the approximation depends on the bandwidth of the circuit you want to analyze with the impulse. A reasonable rule of thumb is that the bandwidth of your circuit should be much less (say 1/10) than the reciprocal of your approximate impulse waveform. For example if you use a 1 microsecond pulse as your impulse, then the bandwidth of your circuit should be less than 1/10 of 1 megaHertz which is 100 kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Impulse is difficult to generate. Dirac-impulse "can't" be.
Ok, but practical waveforms can be made, one as this ...

[image]